# Sum of two maximum patterns in linux file

Tags: linux, shell, awk, centos

I am a newbie in linux. Need help for a command.
I have file in linux with following values:

```
2-1
2-10
2-11
2-12
2-2
2-3
1-1
1-10
1-11
1-2
1-3
1-9
```

Needed output needed is **23**. Sum of maximum from 1- & 2- pattern i.e. 11 from 1-**11** & 12 from 2-**12**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F"-" 'BEGIN{a=0; b=0;} {if(int($1)==1 && int($2)>a){a=int($2)}; if(int($1)==2 && int($2)>b){b=int($2)}}END{print a+b}' file
```

output:

```
23
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk` using `ternary` operator

```
awk -v FS='-' '{m1=($1==1?(m1>$2?m1:$2):m1);m2=($1==2?(m2>$2?m2:$2):m2)}END{print m1+m2}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

**sort** + **awk** pipeline:

```
sort -t- -k2 -n file | awk -F'-' '{a[$1]=$2}END{ print a[1]+a[2] }'
```

The output:

```
23
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'-' '{max[$1] = ($2 > max[$1] ? $2 : max[$1])} END{for (key in max) sum+=max[key]; print sum}' file
23
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F- 'a[$1]<$2{a[$1]=$2}END{for(i in a)s+=a[i]; print s}' infile
23
```